# Getting all Unicode aliases for a codepoint

Tags: perl, unicode

The [`charnames`](https://metacpan.org/pod/charnames) pragma provides `charnames::viacode` which returns the "best" name for a given code point

For instance

```
$ perl -Mcharnames=:full -E'say charnames::viacode(ord "A")'
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
```

Is there a convenient way to discover all known aliases for this name from within Perl?

Comment: `viacode` gets the full list by calling `do "unicore/Name.pl"`, but that's a generated file for internal use only...not sure if there's a public interface to it besides what `charnames` provides.

Comment: Do you want just the Unicode aliases of the code point, or all values that can be used in `\N{}` to produce that code point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the Unicode aliases of a code point, you can use the following:

```
use Unicode::UCD qw( charprop );

my @aliases =
   map { s/:.*//sr }
      split /,/,
         charprop($ucp, "Name_Alias");   # $ucp is the Unicode code point as a number.
```

For example, this returns `SP` for U+0020 SPACE.

The complete list can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NameAliases.txt).

---

For all the values you can pass to `\N{}`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41745993/589924).