# How can I get all values that can be used in \N{} to produce a particular code point?

Tags: perl, unicode

While performing debugging for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738241/perl-unknown-charname-nalpha), I asked myself: How do I find all values that I can use in `\N{}` for a given Unicode code point?

For example, I want to know all aliases for U+03B1 (GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA). How would I find out that `\N{greek:alpha}` could be used for this?

Comment: Related: [Getting all Unicode aliases for a codepoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663788/getting-all-unicode-aliases-for-a-codepoint) (initially flagged as a duplicate, but it sounds like you're asking for all the things you can use in `\N{}` for that codepoint, not just Unicode aliases)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Not quite. `greek:alpha` is something Perl generated; it's not (directly) from the UCD.

Comment: @ikegami Yep, just retracted my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single list against which these are checked.

Based on the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?charnames) of `\N{}`, the following will do the trick:

```
use List::Util   qw( max );
use Unicode::UCD qw( charscripts charinfo charprop );

my $re_scripts = join '|', map { quotemeta uc s/_/ /gr } keys %{ charscripts() };
my $re_letter = qr/^($re_scripts) (?:(CAPITAL|SMALL) )?LETTER (\S.*)/;

{
   @ARGV == 1
     or die("usage\n");

   my $ucp = hex( $ARGV[0] =~ s/^(?:U\+|0x)//r );

   my @names;
   push @names, [ "", sprintf('U+%X', $ucp) ];

   if ( my $charinfo = charinfo($ucp) ) {
      my $name = $charinfo->{name};
      push @names, [ ":full", $name ] if length($name) && $name ne '<control>';

      for my $alias (map s/:.*//sr, split /,/, charprop($ucp, 'Name_Alias')) {
         push @names, [ ":full", $alias ];
      }

      if ( my ($script_name, $type, $short_char_name) = $name =~ $re_letter ) {
         my $uc = ( $type // 'CAPITAL' ) eq 'CAPITAL';
         my $lc = ( $type // 'SMALL'   ) eq 'SMALL';
         push @names, [ ":short", join(":", $script_name, uc($short_char_name)) ] if $uc;
         push @names, [ ":short", join(":", $script_name, lc($short_char_name)) ] if $lc;
         push @names, [ $script_name, uc($short_char_name) ] if $uc;
         push @names, [ $script_name, lc($short_char_name) ] if $lc;
      }
   }

   my $longuest = max map length($_->[0]), @names;
   say sprintf("use charnames qw( %-*s ); \"\\N{%s}\"", $longuest, @$_) for @names;
}
```

For example,

```
$ ./script.pl U+03B1
use charnames qw(        ); "\N{U+3B1}"
use charnames qw( :full  ); "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}"
use charnames qw( :short ); "\N{GREEK:alpha}"
use charnames qw( GREEK  ); "\N{alpha}"

$ ./script.pl U+0391
use charnames qw(        ); "\N{U+391}"
use charnames qw( :full  ); "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA}"
use charnames qw( :short ); "\N{GREEK:ALPHA}"
use charnames qw( GREEK  ); "\N{ALPHA}"

$ perl a.pl 1C00
use charnames qw(        ); "\N{U+1C00}"
use charnames qw( :full  ); "\N{LEPCHA LETTER KA}"
use charnames qw( :short ); "\N{LEPCHA:KA}"
use charnames qw( :short ); "\N{LEPCHA:ka}"
use charnames qw( LEPCHA ); "\N{KA}"
use charnames qw( LEPCHA ); "\N{ka}"

$ ./script.pl 20
use charnames qw(       ); "\N{U+20}"
use charnames qw( :full ); "\N{SPACE}"
use charnames qw( :full ); "\N{SP}"
```

Notes:

- Script names in charnames.pm import parameters are case-insensitive.
- Instances of `use charnames qw( );` in the output (i.e. directives loading charnames.pm with no parameters) are not actually necessary.
- Since Perl 5.16, charnames.pm is implicitly loaded using `use charnames qw( :full :short );` if it's otherwise loaded before a `\N{}` is encountered.
- Custom aliases in effect are not listed. (Technically, there aren't any unless you modify the script.)
- The names must be provided exactly as output, with the following exceptions:

  - The number that follows `U+` is case-insensitive.
  - The number that follows `U+` may have leading zeroes.
  - The script name in `:short` names is case-insensitive.
  - Upper-case character names in `:short` and in script character names are case-insensitive, but must contain at least one upper-case character.
  - Using `use charnames qw( :loose );` allows further variations of the displayed strings.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, No, it has nothing to do with the UCD other than it uses it. I could be placed on CPAN in a separate module, but it's of very limited use since it doesn't produce anything comparable. It's kinda like asking for a sub that produces all strings a regex pattern will match. The function I posted does little more than document `\N{}`, and even then, it only does so with all the accompanying notes which are longer than the actual  [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?charnames) for `\N{}`.

Comment: Just great! Exactly what I was searching for